# Datatables ServerSide sort not working. What has gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables with server side processing. Everything works fine, except the sort function. It doesn't show any errors in the console. What could be happening?

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
        'paging': true,
        'info': true,
        'filter': true,
        'stateSave': true,
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'aaSorting': [[2, 'asc']],
        'bSortable': true,
        'bProcessing': true,
});
```

Comment: What do you use as serverside hanler script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you process sorting on the server side?
That's what datatables is sending to the server:

```
order[0][column]:column_number
order[0][dir]:direction(asc|desc)
```

Column number is 0-based
You have to sort the data on the server side.

Comment: Thanks! now i see, but how can i obtaint that value?... some like
            $search = $this->input->post('search')['value'];

Comment: It depends on what you're using for the backend. For controller in symfony i do this - $this->get('order');